# Could not open /var/folders/n_/ laravel-excel.maatwebsite

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

i want to create download excel function using laravel-excel.maatwebsitelibrary. my code like below :

```
return Excel::download(new PembukuanExport, 'pembukuan.xlsx');
```

but when i ran it, it gave me error like this

> Could not open /var/folders/n_/xh_10hm50dvbwg23cfq_kw3h0000gn/T/laravel-excel-DMBN3reNUrSiamYT for writing.

[image]

my laptop is macbook, been googling but cant find the right answer

Comment: Check this folder writeable or not? Provide write permission to this folder.

Comment: it is writable, i have chmod that folder but still getting error..

Comment: is there any way for me to change the writing folder ?

Comment: Try giving  chmod -R 775 to the folder ?

Answer (score 6):

It might be too late to answer this, but I guess you need to configure your `excel.php` config files.

Publish excel config files:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider"
```

Now in `config/excel.php` files you need to do configuration:

```
'temporary_files' => [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Local Temporary Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When exporting and importing files, we use a temporary file, before
    | storing reading or downloading. Here you can customize that path.
    |
    */
    'local_path'  => storage_path(),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Remote Temporary Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When dealing with a multi server setup with queues in which you
    | cannot rely on having a shared local temporary path, you might
    | want to store the temporary file on a shared disk. During the
    | queue executing, we'll retrieve the temporary file from that
    | location instead. When left to null, it will always use
    | the local path. This setting only has effect when using
    | in conjunction with queued imports and exports.
    |
    */
    'remote_disk' => null,

],
```

This will set the temporary folder to your storage path which has permission to execute things. Hope this find helpful to others.

Comment: I ran into this same issue and found your answer. I have published excel config as you adviced but still having the same error even after running `php artisan config:cache` command. This is the current part `'local_path'          => storage_path('framework/laravel-excel'),`

Any more tips on what I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

i solved this by changing `User & Group` in `httpd.conf.

1. Open `httpd.config`.
2. Search keyword "User or Group" and change it.
3. `User your_mac_user` and fill in `Group staff`